# Wordpress: Space between the slugs

Tags: php, wordpress, space

I have this code to display the slugs of the post:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'project-category' ); foreach($terms as $term){ echo $term->slug; } ?>
```

But now they are sticky to each other like:

> cateogry-01cateogry-02

How can i make it like:

> cateogry-01 cateogry-02

Comment: `implode(' ',array_map(function ($a) { return $a->slug;},$terms));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
echo $term->slug;
```

to:

```
echo $term->slug . ' ';
```

Comment: extra space at the end